# have character \ in result of rest service using CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, rest

i create post method :

```
class login extends REST_Controller {

    function user_post() {

            $re = array (
                'code' => '0',
                'result' => "loi roi",
                'data' => "lp cp",

            );

            $this->response(json_encode($re));

    }

}
```

after use WebRequest in c#, i have this string :

```
"{\"code\":\"0\",\"result\":\"loi roi\",\"data\":\"lp cp\"}"
```

but the string i want: 
 {"code":"0","result":"loi roi","data\":"lp cp"}

why have character in result ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be double encoding a json object. Your `REST_Controller::response` method will encode what you give it to if the output format is json (assuming you are using [this library](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver)). Just drop the `json_encode()` before you pass the `$re`.